# Nservicekit deserialization

Tags: javascript, c#, post, servicestack

i'm trying to post an object to an nservicekit webservice, the request has my object but the properties are unaffected. But when i deserialize using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject my list object get populated correctly.
Can someone help me on this one? what am i doing wrong?
Thank you.

I'm using the following code to achive

```
[Route("/LogbookRegistries", Summary = @"Posts an List type of LogbookRegistry")]
public class LogbookRegistries
{
    public List<LogBookRegistry> list { get; set; }
}
public class LogbookRegistriesService : Service
{
    public object Options(LogbookRegistries request)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public LogbookRegistriesResponse Post(LogbookRegistries request)
    {
        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LogBookRegistry>>(Request.FormData["list"]) ;

        Boolean thereAreErrors = false;

      //  if (request.LogbookRegistriesList == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Cant continue passed data is null");
        try
        {
           // DataBase.SaveList<LogBookRegistry>(request.LogbookRegistriesList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            thereAreErrors = true;
        }

        return new LogbookRegistriesResponse { ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus { Message = thereAreErrors ? @"There were errors while saving data." : @"Posted data saved succesfully." } };
    }
    public LogbookRegistriesResponse Get(LogbookRegistries request)
    {
        var list = DataBase.GetAll<LogBookRegistry>();
        return new LogbookRegistriesResponse { Data=list };
    }
}
public class LogbookRegistriesResponse
{
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    public List<LogBookRegistry> Data {get;set;}
}

public partial class LogBookRegistry
{
    public LogBookRegistry()
    {
        this.LogBookRegistryDetails = new HashSet<LogBookRegistryDetail>();
    }


    public string code { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int locationId { get; set; }
    public int actionTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> deviceId { get; set; }
    public string remarks { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LogBookRegistryDetail> LogBookRegistryDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
}
```

an from javascript side i'm using

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost:49321/LogbookRegistries?',
            data:  {"list":JSON.stringify( [
                        {
                            "LogRegistryDetails": "",
                            "id": "0",
                            "locationId": "2",
                            "actionTypeId": "2",
                            "code": "TRP-OUT-Palmetal-20150310_151929",
                            "active": "true",
                            "date": "2015-03-10 15:19:29",
                            "deviceId": "1",
                            "remarks": ""
                        }
             ])} ,
           dataType: 'json',

        })
            .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                debugger;
                alert('done');
            })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            debugger;
            alert('fail');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `JSON.stringify()` the entire JSON data object, not just the list item array. Then ServiceStack can deserialise the request automatically.

```js
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:49321/LogbookRegistries?',
        data:  JSON.stringify( {"list":[
                    {
                        "LogRegistryDetails": "",
                        "id": "0",
                        "locationId": "2",
                        "actionTypeId": "2",
                        "code": "TRP-OUT-Palmetal-20150310_151929",
                        "active": "true",
                        "date": "2015-03-10 15:19:29",
                        "deviceId": "1",
                        "remarks": ""
                    }
         ]}) ,
       dataType: 'json',

    })
    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            debugger;
            alert('done');
        })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger;
        alert('fail');
    });
```

Comment: Sorry for the late "comment". I must be doing something wrong because if i try  to do like you sugest the list is null on the request. What can i possible doing wrong?